# File permission

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, file, linux

Using `Linux`,`centos7`,`cloud server`.having `3` accouts.
About file permission, sometime getting warning can't inside the website, need to refresh 2~3 times.

How to fix file permission, we don't want every time make command for `sudo chmod -R -v 777 var`

Please help , thank you!

```
{"0":"Warning: file_put_contents(\/home\/xxx\/public_html\/var\/cache\/\/mage-tags\/mage---b8e_CONFIG): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
```